# string from reading file "keyname"=>"stuff","keyname2","more stuff" convert to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array stated in a codeigniter  class in libraries like

```
$this->myArray =("keyname1"=>"fashion bags,accessories," ,"keyname2"=>"aplaku");
```

It works fine for what I want to do, but the array is going to get longer as my web expands and its a pain to manage like this.

So i put the array data into into  sometext.txt , in the form as `"keyname1"=>"stuff","keyname2"=>"stuff"`

then I put it in the extra folder of codeigniter and load it using  `$this->load->helper('file');`  and then use 
 `$someString = read_file('extra/data.txt');`   if I echo $someString I get:
`"keyname1"=>"stuff","keyname2"=>"stuff"`

the next thing I want to do is `$this->myArray = array($someString);`

It doesn't work and the issue seems to be string to array conversion

I did once use `$this->anArray =   func_get_args($data);` but this is only for
arrays with index `[0] [1]`... etc

so if

```
$string = "keyname1","stuff","keyname2", "stuff"; //how do I do the next line
   $someArray =array( $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before save you can encode the array to a json and when you retreve back you can decode json. 
use`json_encode($arr)` for encode to json and use `json_decode ($json)` when retreving.